# Only some attributes are displayed on my decision tree with fitctree from Matlab

Tags: matlab, decision-tree

I need to build a decision tree with Matlab. I use fitctree function. My set of data contains 27 predictors and 4 outputs (class labels) possible which are {2;3;5;7}. However, when I plot the tree, I only get 2 attributes (with a 3-level tree) as you can see on [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqHIJ.jpg).

Did I miss something with the decision tree theorie? 
Should I use a bag of trees? If so, why is this the solution and how many trees should I plot? How to interpret the information?

I really thank you in advance,

Iconoclastor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that all 4 classes can be distinguished by the tree using three attributes. There is no point in artifically adding more attributes to it. 
Actually it is a good thing if a problem requires less attributes to be solved. In your case you can even visualize the decision in a 3D-space, making your problem perfectly interpretable.

A bag of trees is just a collection or ensemble of trees, all doing the same task on a limited input dataseet. So instead of feeding all your training data to one tree, you grow multiple trees, but each of them only with a subset of the original data. Finally the results of all trees are combined.